# Jekyll/Liquid mergin a page with extra data from _data

Tags: merge, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to merge a page with extra data.

There is now output if I do it the following way.

```
{% assign extra = site.data.extra | where_exp: "search", "search.stg_kurz == page.stg_kurz" %}
  {{ extra.teaser | markdownify }}
```

But if I do it that way, there is an output, but why?

```
{% assign extras = site.data.extra | where_exp: "search", "search.stg_kurz == page.stg_kurz" %}
  {{ extras.teaser | markdownify }}
  {% for extra in extras %}
    {{ extra.teaser | markdownify }}
  {% endfor %}
```

There is always only one dataset, that matches the page.variable

Can anyone help or has some tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My own solution looks like

```
{% assign stg = site.data.3478_fachrichtung | where_exp: "search", "search.stg_kurz == page.stg_kurz" %}
  {% assign extras = site.data.extra | where_exp: "search", "search.stg_kurz == page.stg_kurz" %}
  {% assign extra = stg | concat: extras %}
```

Not perfekt, but it works for me.

`site.data.3478_fachrichtung` is the page.data

Has anyone a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

`{% assign extra = site.data.extra | where_exp: .... %}` returns an array containing (normally) one element. You just have to grab it with `first` array filter before printing it.

```
{% assign extras = site.data.extra | where_exp: "search", "search.stg_kurz == page.stg_kurz" %}
{% assign extra = extras.first %}
{{ extra.teaser | markdownify }}
```